# Swapping rows and columns in a "Group by" query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I currently have the following:

```
SELECT status,count(status) AS count
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[contact]
  GROUP BY status
```

Which gives me the following:

```
Status 1   |   12
Status 2   |   23
Status 3   |   63
```

I'm trying to get the table to look like this:

```
Status 1   Status 2   Status 3  
   12        23         63
```

Eventually the table will look like this:

```
                 Status 1   Status 2   Status 3  
Date Range 1        12        23         63
Date Range 2        23        2           3
```

I'm just not sure what to do now.  What kind of SQL commands / syntax should I study to get this done?  This is my first time looking at SQL so any pointers would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like this which will get you the data in the correct format:

```
SELECT 
  sum(case when status = 'Status 1' then 1 else 0 end) Status1,
  sum(case when status = 'Status 2' then 1 else 0 end) Status2,
  sum(case when status = 'Status 3' then 1 else 0 end) Status3
FROM [DB].[dbo].[contact]
```

In SQL Server you can even use the `PIVOT` function to transform the data:

```
select [Status 1] as Status1, 
  [Status 2] as Status2, 
  [Status 3] as Status3
from 
(
  SELECT status, status as statusToCount
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[contact]
) src
pivot
(
  count(statusToCount)
  for status in ([Status 1], [Status 2], [Status 3])
) piv
```

Comment: How would you suggest applying the date filter to the columns, assuming one regular date range per row?

Comment: @RobVious There might be a few ways to do it, can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data including the dates?

Comment: @RobVious is created supposed to be a date?

Comment: yes, I just made it an int to keep things simpler.  I can change types later or now, whichever you think is best

Comment: @RobVious seeing actual data is easier considering you want the result to be to show some sort of a date range.

Comment: Got it!  I just added more data and changed the datatype to DATETIME

Comment: @RobVious what is the new sql fiddle link?  it changes each time you update it.

Comment: @RobVious what date range do you want on the results?

Comment: I'd like to try and add five rows - one for each month.  In use this will be one for each week for the past 52 weeks.  

By the way - thanks again for the help.  This is awesome.

Comment: @RobVious sounds like maybe you want this -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05eab/12 -- gives the total count for each created date

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could use Group By like that.  

The rows will actually have to be ranges instead of particular dates, since cases will be created every day.  Is there any way to do that within the Query?  Something like "For each week where case date is within the week, group by status"?

Comment: @RobVious yes you should be able to group by a date range, you will have to play with it in your system.  Then if you have any more problems/questions post a new question and people with help out